# Rewriting query in order to remove FIND_IN_SET?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

My mysql query looks like this:

```
    SELECT pages.*,
           showcase.*,
           project.*    
      FROM pages
INNER JOIN showcase ON showcase.pid = pages.uid AND showcase.deleted != 1
INNER JOIN project ON FIND_IN_SET(project.uid, showcase.projects)   
     WHERE pages.deleted != 1
       AND pages.pid = 14
       AND pages.dokType = 150
```

The problem is the second `INNER JOIN` - it uses `FIND_IN_SET` because a showcase (= collection of projects) stores its projects as a comma separated list in the field `showcase.projects`. `FIND_IN_SET` cant use indexes as far as I know, so the second join requires a full table scan of the project table. Any possibility to use an index without changing the database scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You searching for a 'string' inside another string. You'll have to do a scan regardless. The other optimized way to do this using indexes is to use a join table. Create a new table `showcase_projects` that has columns of `project_id` and `showcase_id`. This will then have a record for every association between the two.

Now this answer is based on my primitive understanding of your datastructure from this query.

Comment: Guess you are right, I will start normalizing the data on monday. Surely the best solution.

Comment: Good luck. Just don't go off the deepend on the normalization :) It can introduce performance / dealing with data concerns in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Is `showcase.projects` a `VARCHAR`? Then you could use `REGEXP` like this:

```
...
INNER JOIN project ON
showcase.projects REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', project.uid, '[[:>:]]')
WHERE ...
```

This expression looks for whole words only (the bracket constructions mark left and right word boundaries, respectively. However, I'm not sure this will be able to make use of an index, maybe someone can come up with something smarter.